# How to bind data tables from lists in nested list?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table, bind

I have a nested list dt_list, which contains in itself lists: dt_list1, dt_list2, dt_list3.
Each of these three lists contains data tables with same names: dt1, dt2, dt3. So I can get dt1 of dt_list1 like this:

```
dt_list[["dt_list1"]][["dt1"]]
```

It will give data table:

```
ID    timestamp     type
AA   2020-10-01    user
A1   2020-10-01    administrator
BA   2020-10-01    user
```

and

```
dt_list[["dt_list2"]][["dt1"]]
```

will give:

```
ID    timestamp     type
KB   2020-10-02    new_user
AA   2020-10-02    administrator
BB   2020-10-02    user
```

I want to bind columns ID and type to get:

```
ID    type
AA    user
A1    administrator
BA    user
KB    new_user
AA    administrator
BB    user
```

I want to bind like that all "dt1" data tables from all three sublists dt_list1, dt_list2, dt_list3 using data.table::rbindlist() function. Binding two of them can be done like this:

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(dt_list[["dt_list1"]][["dt1"]], dt_list[["dt_list2"]][["dt1"]]))
```

It will bind two necessary dataframes. But I want to bind all three with iteration, not one by one (because there can be not three sublists, but 20 and one by one is not efficient in that case).  I think a function which will bind all data tables dt1 from all sublists is the best solution. data.table library must be used for that

Comment: Maybe something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(dt_list, "[[", "dt1"))` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[[` in `lapply` and `rbind` the result and remove column 2 with `[-2]`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dt_list, "[[", "dt1"))[-2]
#           ID type
#dt_list1.1  1    a
#dt_list1.2  2    a
#dt_list2.1  1    b
#dt_list2.2  2    b
#dt_list3.1  1    c
#dt_list3.2  2    c
```

Data:

```
dt_list <- list(dt_list1 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="a"))
          , dt_list2 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="b"))
          , dt_list3 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="c")))
```

Comment: i need to use data.table functions, it must be rbindlist()

Comment: Maybe in this case: `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(dt_list, "[[", "dt1"))[,-2]`

Comment: thanks, and if dt1 is in one more sublist deeper, should I use lapply(dt_list, "[[[[", "dt1") than?

Comment: Than you can use `lapply` in `lapply` or define a `function`.

Comment: like this ```lapply(lapply(dt_list, "[[", "dt1"), "[[",  "dt1")``` ?

Comment: Can you provide an example data set for that case?

Comment: if its like this for example: ```dt_list <- list(dt_list1 = list(another_list1 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="a")))
                , dt_list2 = list(another_list2 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="b")))
                , dt_list3 = list(another_list3 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="c"))))```

Comment: In that case I would use something like: `do.call(rbind, lapply(unlist(dt_list, FALSE), "[[", "dt1"))[-2]`

Comment: so for each new sublist layer enlist must be applied? like ```do.call(rbind, lapply(unlist (unlist(dt_list, FALSE),FALSE), "[[", "dt1"))[-2]```  for another sublist and so on?

Comment: Have also a look at `rapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package that easily extends to deeper nested lists:

```r
## extract data.frames from nested list
(dt_flat <- rrapply::rrapply(dt_list, classes = "data.frame", how = "flatten"))
#> $dt1
#>   ID time type
#> 1  1    2    a
#> 2  2    2    a
#> 
#> $dt1
#>   ID time type
#> 1  1    2    b
#> 2  2    2    b
#> 
#> $dt1
#>   ID time type
#> 1  1    2    c
#> 2  2    2    c

## bind together
data.table::rbindlist(dt_flat)
#>    ID time type
#> 1:  1    2    a
#> 2:  2    2    a
#> 3:  1    2    b
#> 4:  2    2    b
#> 5:  1    2    c
#> 6:  2    2    c
```

---

If you want to filter only the `dt1` data.frames, you can add an additional `condition` argument:

```r
## extract dt1 data.frames from nested list
rrapply::rrapply(dt_list, classes = "data.frame", condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "dt1", how = "flatten")
#> $dt1
#>   ID time type
#> 1  1    2    a
#> 2  2    2    a
#> 
#> $dt1
#>   ID time type
#> 1  1    2    b
#> 2  2    2    b
#> 
#> $dt1
#>   ID time type
#> 1  1    2    c
#> 2  2    2    c
```

**Data**

```
dt_list <- list(dt_list1 = list(another_list1 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="a"))),               
                dt_list2 = list(another_list2 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="b"))),                
                dt_list3 = list(another_list3 = list(dt1 = data.frame(ID=1:2, time=2, type="c"))))
```